# Is there a different way to hide a scope variable from showing while AngularJS is loading?

Tags: angularjs

I am using this way:

```
<div ng-cloak>{{ message.userName || message.text }}</div>
```

Is this the only / best way to ensure the user does not see the {{ }} when AngularJS is still loading ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to hide content before Angular has a chance to run

- Put the content you want to hide in another template, and use [`ngInclude`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)

  ```
  <div ng-include="'myPartialTemplate.html'"></div>
  ```

  If you don't actually want another request made to the server to fetch another file, there are a couple of ways, as explained in the [`$templateCache` docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24templateCache). There are tools to "compile" external HTML templates into JS to avoid having to do this manually, such as [grunt-angular-templates](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-angular-templates).
- Similar to `ngInclude`, if you put everything in [custom directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), with its own template, then the template content won't be shown until Angular has had a chance to run.

  ```
  <my-directive></my-directive>
  ```

  With a definition of:

  ```
  app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<div>Content hidden until Angular loaded</div>'
    }
  });
  ```
- [`ngBind`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind) as an alternative to `{{}}` blocks

  ```
  <div>Hello <span ng-bind="name"></span></div>
  ```
- [`ngCloak`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) as you have mentioned (in this list for completeness).

  ```
  <div ng-cloak>Content hidden until Angular compiled the template</div>
  ```

  But you must have certain styles loaded before the page is rendered by the browser, as explained in the [`ngCloak` docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-bind` too as the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind) explains.

A typical advantage about `ng-bind` is the ability to provide a default value while Angular is loading (indeed, `ng-cloak` can only **hide** the content):

```
<p>Hello, <span ng-bind="user.name">MyDefaultValueWhileAngularIsLoading<span/></p>
```

Then as soon Angular is loaded, the value will be replaced by `user.name`.

Besides, `ng-cloak` is useful when dealing with **blocks** (many HTML lines) and `ng-bind` on a particular element.

Comment: Is there any difference or is one recommended over the other? Also can I use ng-bind in this case where I have some condition in there that shows one if the other is null ?