# How to load data from angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new in working on angular js, while loading data sometimes on firefox it shows variable name and after few section it shows the content of that variable in a proper way. How can I load this data or how can I apply loader to load data. As you can view in below screenshot.

[image]

After some moment, it shows proper content 
[image]

Comment: a quick fix to this can be `ng-cloak`. this hides those angular expression till they are parsed and populated by angularjs.

Comment: This has been asked to many times check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23453396/is-there-a-different-way-to-hide-a-scope-variable-from-showing-while-angularjs-i

Comment: Do not use evaluation expressions in visible part of the DOM. This is very good point from behalf of different sides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ng-cloak. It goes like that:

CSS:

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-cloak> ... </body>
```

will work, but it will hide whole body. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak:

> The directive can be applied to the  element, but the preferred usage is to apply multiple ngCloak directives to small portions of the page to permit progressive rendering of the browser view.

so it's better to apply `ng-cloak` to particular elements:

```
<div ng-cloak> ... </div>
<div ng-cloak> ... </div>
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21295787/4989081) is well described how to add loading info.

Comment: This works how can I apply loader that load on every page ?

Comment: Have you tried `<body ng-cloak> ... </body>` in index.html?

Comment: That I have tried but it's a bad format to load content it shows first header logo then body button, footer, then header menus bla bla . .. .......I need first show a loader and once all content loaded on page then to show page content and images.

Comment: As it is stated it is better to apply `ng-cloak` to small portions of the page to permit progressive rendering of the browser view. So it's better to add it not globaly, but in places (elements) where it's needed.

Comment: Okay, do you have any idea to show loader and once th content ready to load then only show content with images using angular js ? like https://breather.com/locations/new-york

Comment: Just edited post. As it's stated, See http://stackoverflow.com/a/21295787/4989081.

Comment: well, that will require to setup angularjs routing with your page divided in views. Then you can do it while configuring route using resolve property. refer this link for better idea https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#route-resolve-promises

Answer (score 2):

To show a loading screen while data is being loaded you can write a custom directive.

**// directive**

```
app.directive('loading', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {
            scope.isLoading = function () {
                return $http.pendingRequests.length > 0;
            };

            scope.$watch(scope.isLoading, function (v) {
                if (v) {
                    elm.show();
                } else {
                    elm.hide();
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

**Use it like this**

```
<body>
<!-- apply style/css to below div to cover entire page/element on which you want to show loader -->
<div loading>
<!-- add an image tag here with src as any loading gif image -->
</div>
</body>
```